# Which Star Wars book series takes place immediately after Episode 6?

Tags: star-wars, novel, suggested-order

Having read very little Star Wars fiction, yet being a fan of the series, I've decided after watching a Star Wars marathon of all of the movies that I'd start reading the novels to continue the story.  Which book/series should I start with to continue the adventures of Luke Skywalker and company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that the Star Wars expanded universe has been rebooted, the series that takes place right after Return of the Jedi in the new canon is the *Aftermath* trilogy. This is the one to read if you're looking for something that will be consistent with The Force Awakens.

Comment: While technically true in terms of what one may consider true 'book' form - the story immediately picks up on Endor in the canon comic series "Shattered Empire". The events in the comic are followed by / coinciding with events in "Aftermath". The Disney / Lucasfilm Story Group is now ensuring that all media is consistent and interconnected.

Comment: cont: - Timeline of new canon materials - http://comicsalliance.com/star-wars-canon-movie-comic-book-timeline/?trackback=twitter_top_flat_4

Comment: Here's a timeline that's just the novels, but with Legends and new canon timelines side by side for reference: http://yodasdatapad.com/booklist.html

Answer (score 27):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_books), Kathy Tyers' *The Truce at Bakura* looks like the first book after Return of the Jedi chronologically.

That being said, I've always considered Timothy Zahn's *Thrawn* trilogy (starting with *Heir to the Empire*) to be my stand-in for episodes 7-9.  The quality of those books in particular is quite high, and the narrative is largely about the same characters as in the movies.

Comment: And as far as I remember, the quality of "The Truce at Bakura" was not "quite high".

Comment: The *Thrawn* trilogy is epic beyond all reason.

Comment: Agreed on the *Thrawn Trilogy*, those books were so good. Thrawn was an amazing character!

Comment: "Truce at Bakura" starts immediately after the Battle of Endor (they're actually still in orbit!).  But the +1 is for Thrawn

Comment: *Thrawn* is so great because it does not only tell another Star Wars story, it actually expands the story and drives it on.

Comment: "Shadows of the Empire: Evolution" (Graphic Novel) takes place right around the events of Bakura as well.  Though when all-is-said-and-done it's the "Thrawn Trilogy" & "Dark Empire" stories that really shine as sequels.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the book "Courtship of Princess Leia," which occurs after the Truce at Bakura and before the Thrawn Trilogy.

Comment: Actually, Courtship is a sequel to 8 of the X-Wing series of books, (all of which happend between *Bakura* and *Courtship*). There's also Tattooine Ghost and a small Squib story happening right after *Courtship* and STILL before Thrawn

Comment: Courtship is only a sequel to 7 of the X-Wing books, Isards Revenge, book 8, takes place after Courtship of Princess Leia and stars up during the events of the Last Command, the third Thrawn series book. Courtship, however, MUST be before Thrawn becasue the Thrawn Trilogy has a pregnant Leia that happens sometime after she hooks up with Han in Courtship.