# Which order to read the 4 Old Republic novels?

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order, star-wars-the-old-republic

I've just purchased a single e-book containing the four Old Republic novels. They are presented in order of their publishing date: *Fatal Alliance, Deceived, Revan, & Annihilation*, respectively. However, I've since learned the chronological in-universe order is *Revan, Deceived, Fatal Alliance, & Annihilation*.

**Which order is recommended for reading the novels, chronologically or by publish date?**

Comment: Related, pretty sure not a dupe: [Where to start with the Star Wars books?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18890/where-to-start-with-the-star-wars-books)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that question before I wrote mine. Only mentioned 3 of the Old Republic books and didn't necessarily indicate best reading order. Also added the suggested order tag. Thanks Amarillo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked my good friends **Paul S. Kemp** (author of [TOR: Deceived](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Old_Republic:_Deceived)), **Sean Williams** (Author of [TOR: Fatal Alliance](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Old_Republic:_Fatal_Alliance)) and **Drew Karpyshyn** (author of [TOR: Revan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Old_Republic:_Revan) and [TOR: Annihiliation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Old_Republic:_Annihilation))
, what their  thoughts were on reading order.

Some answers were more useful than others :-)

> **Q.** *There are 4 "Old Republic" novels now. Any thoughts on reading order (e.g published vs, in-universe chronological)?*
>
> **[PSK](https://twitter.com/Paulskemp/status/720056076205432832):** *They're all standalone, I think, so any order works.  Pick your poison.*
>
> **[SW](https://twitter.com/adelaidesean/status/720261112860573697):** *Hmmmm. Tricky. Roll a 4-sided dice?*
>
> **[DK](https://twitter.com/DrewKarpyshyn/status/720416621706121216):** *I'd say in-universe chronology, though I think they all basically stand on their own.*
>
> <sub><sup>[via Twitter](https://twitter.com/Paulskemp/status/720056076205432832)</sup></sub>

Comment: Well, aren't we well-connected. Very nice. +1 for personally knowing one of the authors. I've decided to read them in order of publish date.

Comment: @iMerchant - You'll be pleased to hear that only Drew Karpyshyn disagrees with you, and then only slightly.

Comment: I've read DK's Darth Bane trilogy several times. He is one of my favorite authors, not just in Star Wars lore, but favorite period. I was tempted to read his first (Darth Revan), but I figured I would read his book third, as sort of the 'main course' to anticipate and enjoy.

Comment: @iMerchant Richard is well connected... I'm starting to think said connection is RJ45 (or possibly SFP+) with priority routing to the publisher's database and to SE.

Comment: @T.J.L. - You just gotta ask the question to the right people :-P