# Chronological order of Star Wars Literature

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, chronological-order

I have always found the Star Wars Universe intriguing and except for a few "picture books" and some of the kids' books I haven't actually read any of the books. Today, I was trying to determine the order in which to read the accepted canon (EU, G, the works - essentially anything that connects to the books or ties into them).

I have read a few lists (some are linked below). But does anyone have a list that I could use to start at the beginning (farthest canon pre-BBY, to farthest post-BBY).

Thanks. In case it matters, I care about reading more chronologically than about specific factions.

[The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2017/5/4/15299448/star-wars-novels-recommendations)

[The Book Smugglers](https://www.thebooksmugglers.com/2017/07/start-star-wars-expanded-universe.html)

[Edmonton Public Library](https://www.epl.ca/blogs/post/where-to-start-reading-star-wars-books/)

Side note: I have just decided to start actually digging deeper in this Universe, so if my terminology is incorrect - please feel free to correct me or ask me for more details in order to phrase a better question.

**Edit**

I also found this other question ["Where to start with Star Wars Books"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18890/where-to-start-with-the-star-wars-books?rq=1) and while it has some great info, it doesn't really answer my question in terms of chronology.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_books

Comment: And also (for EU/Legends) https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Legends_books

Comment: Just to add sometimes it's hard because a book or a comic sometimes is done with a frame story or flashbacks and therefor, one work can hit multiple eras. In example the current Marvel Star Wars line has small Obi-Wan flashback arc (via character reading his journal) to when he was living on Tatooine and watching over young Luke.

Comment: @DarthLocke that I knew. What I am going for is a list or something like that to focus my reading and if the character POV takes us back in time (your example is perfect). That's fine, the book itself would still be set in (e.g. 2BBY, while the memory may be in 10BBY).

Comment: @JCrosby Then you're best bet is the links provided by DavidW. Wookiepedia is good source showing both canon and "Legends" timelines; there are also "full media" (books, comics, games, tv series, films) timeline page too: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media

Comment: Is reading the Young Reader stuff worthwhile or should I just stick to the "Adultier" stuff? I noticed they were separated in the tables (on the links provided above).

Comment: for new canon, the YA label is sometimes a bit of a misnomer. For example, "Lost Stars" is one of the more well regarded of all the new novels, even though it's YA. Same for the Ahsoka novel, it's listed as YA but that one and Lost Stars could very well be standard novels.

Comment: Until the points I raised on [the meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12724/58193) about this post have been actioned I don't feel like this should be reopened so voting to leave closed.